# Git Clone via SSH Changes README Timestamp: What's Happening?

Tags: git, github, ssh, version-control, git-clone

At about **Mar 12 14:50** today, I issued these git commands:

```
$ cd original
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/UserX/appx.git
$ git push --all origin
$ ls -ltr README
-rw-r--r--. 1 userx userx 4066 Feb 22 04:57 README
```

I then did a: `cd ../fresh`, and...

```
$ git clone git@github.com:UserX/appx.git
$ cd appx
$ ls -ltr README
-rw-r--r--. 1 userx userx 4066 Mar 12 14:50 README
```

Explain why (and where) the date on the README file has changed from **Feb** to today's **Mar**?

[I'm thinking that scp (inside git clone) can preserve dates? And maybe there is a way to preserve dates?]

Comment: "*I'm thinking that scp (inside git clone)…*" There is no `scp` inside Git. Git uses its own completely different protocol. Git stores commit timestamps but it doesn't automatically set it; you need to find out existing scripts that set file timestamps or write your own.

Comment: See my scripts `set-commit-date` and related in https://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=tree . Especially interesting is `set-commit-date.py`. Also look into subdirectory `hooks/post-checkout`.